# Ubuntu 18 - can not use Right-Shift button to change keyboard layout

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I just installed Ubuntu 18 and got surprised by the fact that I can change keyboard layout only by key combinations, not by a single key.

Actually its not a problem yet - I used `gnome-tweak-tool` to change keyboard layout key to <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>. It works. Partially.

I mean, yes, I can change it by <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, but it doesn't works as I expect. In Ubuntu 16 I use <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> too, but I also was able to print capital letters with it, now I can't.

When I press the <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> button, it changes layout immediately, before I can press any other button, so in total it prints lowercase letter in another keyboard layout.

I googled it and didn't find anything even close to my problem.
So Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Seems like a Xorg bug #865 (really???): https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/258
The patch is still not included in main package: https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys
Patch is worked for key combinations - it delays layout changing until you release keys, but still not work with one button. Seems like when i press RShift popup with layouts list is flashing on screen, after this layout changes immediately as earlier.

Comment: Денис, I do not know your habbits, but may be it is time to try [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org)? It is a last resort for users who want to do their work effective and productive. In `mate-keyboard-preferences` it has `<RightCtrl> (while pressed)` option. Also see discussion [on Ubuntu Community site](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/32?u=norbert).

Comment: Thanks, but i prefer use Unity.I think, i just need to make some changes in patch https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xorg-server-bug865/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the tool `xcape`

`sudo apt install xcape`

> Description: Configure modifier keys to act as other keys when pressed
>   and released xcape allows you to use a modifier key as another key
>   when pressed and released on its own. Note that it is slightly slower
>   than pressing the original key, because the pressed event does not
>   occur until the key is released. The default behaviour is to generate
>   the Escape key when Left Control is pressed and released on its own.

once `xcape` is installed run the below command to make Right Shift release act as Super_L+space which is the default keyboard shortcut for keyboard layout change..

`xcape -e 'Shift_R=Super_L|Space'`

this way while Right Shift is held down you can type capital letters and when the key is pressed on its own and released, It will change the keyboard layout..

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt worked for me. 
I want to change layout only when Rshift is released, not immediately when it pressed. Is there any way to approach this?

Comment: It was somehow possible in Ubuntu 16. Moreover, i only set it up in standart settings window and at works well. 
Yes, Im able to type Capital letters with this workaround, but it prints letters in another layout, because it changes layout right when i press RShift. For example, here how it works when i press Rshift+L several times:
ДLДLДLД

Comment: Hi, Answer Edited.. Please have a review..